# Communicating with mining pools

Tags: mining-pools, asic, firmware

if I designed my own ASIC machine, what is the easiest way to connect it with the mining pool? I was searching but couldn't find any pool that has an API to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Mining pools use protocols such as [Stratum](https://braiins.com/stratum-v2) to communicate.

However, I'd find it unusual to implement this in firmware or in an ASIC. I'd expect the ASICs to be dedicated to hashing and have pool communication handled by a supervisory computer. But I've not designed ASICs or mining systems so maybe my intuition here is weak.

Comment: yes that what i am meant, i will build asci machine and then use a computer to handles these asic machines. I have looked for stratum, explored their website too, but couldnt find any documentation of api, or some paltform  where I can find some help. Neither do i find any documentation on pool websites like which protocol are they using etc. where can i find such documents, regards